# Loading application Properties Spring-boot getting null values

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I was trying read the properties from application.properties files  using
@ConfigurationProperties getting null values for the variables, tried Using @Value Also having the same issue with that. Is There any other way to load the properties into application

```
        @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "email")
    public class EmailProperties {enter code here

        private String host;

        private String port;

        private String username ;

        private String password;

        public String getHost() {
            return host;
        }

        public void setHost(String host) {
            this.host = host;
        }

        public String getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort(String port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EmailProperties [host=" + host + ", port=" + port + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password
                    + "]";
        }
```

properties file

```
email.host=test
 email.port=25
 email.username=Test
email.password=Test
```

Method where Using Those properties

```
 @Autowired
    private EmailProperties emailProperties;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void sendMail( String toEmail, String messageSubject, String messageBody) {

        System.out.println("host");

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", false);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", emailProperties.getHost());
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", emailProperties.getPort());
        prop.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", emailProperties.getHost());
```